# Make text color in innerHTML change depending on value in GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html, css

When I hover over different counties on my map, a div updates whether or not the county voted republican or democratic in the 2020 election (among other things). It will either say it voted republican or democrat in a `<h2>` tag.

I have a column in the GeoJSON that has either red or blue hex codes depending on the majority vote of the county. How can I pull the value from that column in the GeoJSON to change the color of the text displayed in the div?

Here's a screenshot of the div

[image]

I want to make the `<h2>` text color (in this county's case "Democrat") correspond to the `elecVaxData_voteColor` value. How can I do this?

Let me know if more info is needed.

Here's the code

```
var map = L.map("map", {
  center: [40, -101],
  zoom: 5,
});

// add basemap
L.tileLayer.provider("CartoDB.PositronNoLabels").addTo(map);

// add basemap labels
map.createPane("baselabels");
map.getPane("baselabels").style.zIndex = 600;
L.tileLayer
  .provider("CartoDB.PositronOnlyLabels", {
    pane: "baselabels",
    interactive: false,
    attribution: '| <a href="https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-County/8xkx-amqh/data">County data</a> | <a href="https://data.cdc.gov/Vaccinations/COVID-19-Vaccinations-in-the-United-States-Jurisdi/unsk-b7fc/data">State data</a> | Map: <a href="https://weircf.wixsite.com/e-portfolio">Chip Weir</a>',
  })
  .addTo(map);

var infoCounties = L.control();
infoCounties.onAdd = function (map) {
  this._div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info"); // create a div with a class "info"
  this.update();
  return this._div;
};

// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
infoCounties.update = function (props) {
  this._div.innerHTML = props ?
    "<b>" +
    props.elecVaxData_county +
    ", " +
    props.elecVaxData_Recip_State +
    " (" +
    props.elecVaxData_PopClass +
    ")" +
    "</b><br /><b>" +
    props.elecVaxData_Series_Complete_Pop_Pct +
    "</b>" +
    " of the population is fully vaccinated " +
    "</b><br /><br />" +
    "This county voted majority " +
    "<h2 style = 'color: props.elecVaxData_voteColor;'>" +
    props.elecVaxData_full +
    "</h2>" +
    " in the 2020 Presidential election" :
    "Hover over a county";
};
infoCounties.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is pretty crude, but without too much focus on all the things that can go wrong and the many ways one could do this better, try changing;

```
"<h2 style = 'color: props.elecVaxData_voteColor;'>"
```

to

```
"<h2 style = 'color: "+props.elecVaxData_voteColor+";'>"
```

to make your property statement part of the JS code instead of the text content, given that props.elecVaxData_voteColor is a valid CSS color.